# The following python code is giving no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing, operators

```
ingredients = ["chocolate", "vanilla", "strawberry"]

if "chocolate" in ingredients:
    if "marshmallow" in ingredients:
        print("Rocky Road")
elif "vanilla" and "strawberry" in ingredients:
    print("Neapolitan")
```

This should print

> Neapolitan

but there is no output in the terminal.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: You are misunderstanding how the `and` operator works

Comment: You are misunderstanding how the `elif` condition works

Comment: also note that `and` has higher precedence than `in`; `"vanilla" and "strawberry" =  "strawberry"`; so this line only tests `"strawberry" in ingredients`.

Answer (score 0):

When "chocolate" is in 'ingredients', your if/else block ends because the condition ends. In order to reach other statement:

```
if "chocolate" in ingredients:

    if "marshmallow" in ingredients:

        print("Rocky Road")

if "vanilla" and "strawberry" in ingredients:

    print("Neapolitan")
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "chocolate" in ingredients and "marshmallow" in ingredients:

    print("Rocky Road")

if "vanilla" in ingredients and "strawberry" in ingredients:

    print("Neapolitan")
```

or

```
if "chocolate" in ingredients:
    if "marshmallow" in ingredients:
        print("Rocky Road")

if "vanilla" in ingredients:
    if "strawberry" in ingredients:
        print("Neapolitan")
```